# Replace whitespaces with comma ignoring whitespaces in quotes

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a string of words separated by whitespace. Need to replace whitespaces with comma ignoring whitespaces in quotes.

```
>>> some_string = 'one two "three four" five "six seven"'
>>> replace_func(some_string)
'one,two,"three four",five,"six seven"'
```

Here is the simple decision:

```
def replace_func(some_str):
    lines = []
    i = 1
    for l in struct.split('"'):
        if i % 2:
            lines.append(l.replace(' ', ',')
        else:
            lines.append(l)
        i += 1

    parsed_struct = '"'.join(lines)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be easily done with the help of [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> ','.join(shlex.split(some_string))
'one,two,three four,five,six seven'
```

I you need to preserve quotation marks you can do this:

```
>>> ','.join(['"{0}"'.format(fragment) if ' ' in fragment else fragment
...           for fragment in shlex.split(some_string)])
'one,two,"three four",five,"six seven"'
```

Comment: This will remove the double quotes as well, which is not what the SO wants

Comment: @MohamedKhamis Thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer to take that into account.

Comment: perfect!  good thing i saw this before i posted my own kludge!

Comment: thanx very much, i need to dig into standart python libraries

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you could try this more simplistic solution with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> ','.join(re.findall('\"[^\"]*\"|\S+', some_string))
'one,two,"three four",five,"six seven"'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using regular expressions:

```
result = re.sub(' (?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', ",", subject)
```

This matches a space and replaces it with a comma only if an even number of quotes follows it. Therefore, it will only match outside of strings.

Comment: i like regular expressions, thanx for your solution

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing is often easier to read and understand later than a regular expression:

```
>>> some_string = 'one two "three four" five "six seven"'
>>> from pyparsing import OneOrMore, quotedString, Word, printables
>>> ','.join(OneOrMore(quotedString | Word(printables)).parseString(some_string))
'one,two,"three four",five,"six seven"'
```